# Can you add an image to the HTML element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using the following code, but it is having no effect!! Can this be done?

```
    html {
          background: #d9dbdc url('images/repeat-x.png') repeat-x;
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to add that image to `body{}` I believe... Other than that, just make sure the path is valid.

Comment: html is not an html element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you actually have an image at the specified location, although it's usually applied to the `body` element. It could be that the body element has a background colour that is covering the image.

Note that paths are relative to the *style sheet file*, not the HTML file embedding it, so a path pointing to `images/repeat-x.png` in `/css/styles.css` would result in `/css/images/repeat-x.png`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done, but it needs to be on the `<body>` tag.

Your image might not exist, or you might have a different background covering it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the background of the entire page I'd recommend:

body {
          background: #d9dbdc url('images/repeat-x.png') repeat-x;
    }

Answer (score 0):

make sure the url is correct, you can use browser debug tool like Firebug in firefox to inspect the html

Comment: If you're using Chrome you can do a right click on page, click "Inspect Element" and on the Resources tab you can find the resource and see if its missing.

Comment: short cut is ctrl +shift + J :)